# Django URL regex for alphanumeric string

Tags: python, regex, django, python-3.x

My current url pattern is:

```
url(r'^(?P<category>\w+)/(?P<hash>\w+)/$', article, name='article'),
```

hash is an alphanumeric string that can be uppercase or lowercase.

example: `gqaBittXW9hcyO`

What should my url pattern look like to operate for this?

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /news/gqaBittXW9hcyO/
Reverse for 'article' with keyword arguments '{'id': 1, 'category': 'news'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<category>\\w+)/(?P<hash>\\w+)/$']
```

**views**

```
def article(request, category, hash, extra_context=None):

    name = resolve(request.path).kwargs['category']
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, hash=hash, entered_category=name)
    print('Hash:', instance.hash) #prints correctly (gqaBittXW9hcyO)

    context = {
        'id': instance.id,
        'instance': instance,
    }

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

Comment: Current pattern should work fine. What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that somewhere (probably your template) you tried to create a URL with the name `article` with arguments `{'id': 1, 'category': 'news'}`. But the way you've defined it, you can't construct an `article` URL using an `id`, you need a `hash`.

The URL `/news/gqaBittXW9hcyO/` is not related to this error, it matched correctly.

Comment: yes you're right, there was a URL with the name `article` with arguments `{'id': 1, 'category': 'news'}` hiding somewhere in the template. All fixed now, thanks.